# specific track breaking soundcloud api

Tags: soundcloud

I'm scanning through recent tracks on SoundCloud but for a certain timeframe of created_at I consistently get a 500 internal server error.

We've been able to pinpoint it to a particular track; i.e. if we use limit and offset to get the track before and after this particular track, the api returns just fine. Requesting data on the particular track also results in a 500 error code: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159004781?client_id=xxx (with a correct client_id of course).

- Does anyone know of this issue?
- Can it be solved?
- Is it a more general issue?
- If so, is there a suggested way to guard against this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Frens Jan